# Applying kernels to separate dimensions in gpytorch

Tags: pytorch, torch, gaussian-process, gpytorch

I am translating three-dimensional Gaussian process regression code from GPflow into GPyTorch to take advantage of PyTorch's native scalability for exact GPR.

[This example](https://docs.gpytorch.ai/en/v1.1.1/examples/08_Advanced_Usage/Simple_GP_Regression_Derivative_Information_2d.html) is helpful, but can't find an explanation for how to apply distinct kernels to individual dimensions in a multi-dimensional GPR (e.g. a Matern52 kernel to dimensions [0,1], and a Matern 32 kernel to dimension [2]).

Does GPyTorch support that functionality, and if so how is it implemented/where can I find an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "active_dims" in the kernel functions :

from(https://docs.gpytorch.ai/en/v1.1.1/kernels.html#rbfkernel)
active_dims (tuple of ints, optional):
Set this if you want to compute the covariance of only a few input dimensions. The ints corresponds to the indices of the dimensions. Default: None.